# Wordpress: I want latest one product from all categories display on the page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want latest one product from all categories display on the page in wordpress , when we add more categories and products in it then it should have to be add(display) on the page with its single latest product.How we can do this? please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get all the product categories with at least a single post using the `hide_empty`.

Then loop through each category and run a query for each to get the single product.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $product_category->slug
                )
            ),

        );
        $products = new WP_Query( $args );
        echo "<ul>";
        while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
            $products->the_post();
            ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jainil sir , Thank You so much for your valuable feedback , sir where should i paste these code, i'm new for wordpress

Comment: @AkshayShelke in your template file where you want to show the product list.

Comment: Thank You sir , yes i have done , your answer is really helpfull

Comment: @AkshayShelke please mark the answer as approved if it is working for you.